# How to use networx to get the probability distribution from a graph

Tags: python, plot, networkx

I need to plot a graph of largest connected components of a graph `G5` against the probability distribution of the same graph using `networkx` library. I have managed to use `networkx.largest_connected_components(Graph)` function to get a list of the largest connected components of the same. Now I need to access the probability distribution of the same graph and plot it against the largest connected components so that I can analyze the increase in probability effect on the largest connected components, below is my python file...

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
import random
random.seed()
n = random.randint(0, 1000)
s = random.randint(1,20)
prob = 0.5
G5 = nx.gnp_random_graph(n,prob,s, False)
##get the largest connected components using nx
largest=max(nx.largest_connected_components(G5),key=len)
##get the probability distribution
##i need help with using networkx to get the probability distribution
##of the graph G5 so i can plot with matplotlib
plt.xlabel('Probablity')
plt.ylabel('Largest Connected Component')
plt.show()
```

Comment: In your code, where is G5 coming from? And what is your definition of "probability distribution from a graph"?

Comment: @Lagerbaer, code has been updated with your requirements

Comment: @Lagerbaer, I think its just probability, am editing the question to change that

Comment: Let me try to clarify what you're asking (because it's not clear at all). Are you trying to understand what's the average size of the largest connected component when `prob` changes? So for example if `prob=0.1` we expect to have a small largest connected component, but if `prob` is larger then also the largest connected component will be larger. Is that what you want?

Comment: You already have the probability `prob` used to generate the random graph `G5`. What is the "probability distribution" of `G5`?

Comment: @RiccardoBucco, exactly that is what I intend to achieve

Comment: But then why do you need "help with using networkx to get the probability distribution of the graph G5"?? You already have it, it's `prob`!

Comment: @RiccardoBucco, but prob is just a single value, the plot function of pyplot needs an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import networkx as nx

n_nodes = 1000 # number of nodes in the graph
n = 100 # number of points in the graph

h = 1 / (n - 1)
x = [h * i for i in range(n)]
y = [max(nx.connected_components(nx.gnp_random_graph(n_nodes, prob)),
         key=len)
     for prob in x]
```

Now you have x and y and you can plot them in a graph